# problem in training RNN using bert embeddings

Tags: neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, sentiment-analysis, embedding, bert-language-model

I have been working with bert embedding using a neural network model for the sentiment classification task. during model fit it's giving indices error, and I am still new to this so could not able to find the reason for the error and how to resolve this.

snippet for the model am trying to build

[image]

error

[image]

Comment: By reading the cut message, it is telling you that the argument you passed is invalid. Can you put the full error message after the word "WARNING"? Maybe you can get some light there, since it looks like a shape mismatch, or that you have given the wrong input variable.

Comment: HERE am trying to read embeddings from bert that have stored in features variable, the shape of that is 6420, 720 and type is ND ARRAY. this the full warning message what am getting WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 40) for input Tensor("embedding_6_input:0", shape=(None, 40), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (8, 1024).

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, error etc. Copy the original text here and format it properly